# What's the longest streak of games with homeruns for a batter?

Tags: baseball, mlb, records, home-run

On August 15 2017 Giancarlo Stanton hit a homerun for a 6th straight games. This has made me to know the followings

- What is the longest number of consecutive games for a player with homeruns?
- What is the most number of homeruns hit in a streak of consecutive games with homers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As of 16 August 2017](http://www.espn.com/mlb/news/story?id=1786653), the record stands at 8 consecutive games with a home run, and that is held by 3 people.

1. Dale Long - Pittsburgh Pirates - May 19 - 28th 1956 (8 Home Runs hit)
2. Don Mattingly - New York Yankees - July 8th - 18th 1987 (10 Home Runs hit)
3. Ken Griffey Jr - Seattle Mariners - July 20th - 28th 1993 (8 Home Runs hit)

[Another source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_individual_streaks)

Comment: Wooow 10 homers in 8 games!